# How to prevent Tapestry from duplicating HTML on zone updates?

Tags: html, ajax, duplicates, tapestry, zone

I'm having a similar problem as described here: (http://apache-tapestry-mailing-list-archives.1045711.n5.nabble.com/Zone-refresh-inserts-duplicate-html-td5722328.html)

When I'm sorting my `Grid` (with custom provided `GridDataSource` that pulls data from the database, the sorting is done on DB side) by clicking on the sorting icons, my grid gets duplicated, as in a copy of the current grid is shown below it. Any following grid sort events only affect the grid I'm clicking the sort column on. For example, if I click to sort the by 1st column in 1st grid, the 2nd grid is unaffected and vice-versa. When I refresh my page, 2nd grid disappears and things go from square 1 again.

I have tried the advice from Thiago H. de Paula Figueiredo saying I could try passing the zone's body instead of zone itself to `addRender` method, but to no result.

Edit: added code.

My Page structure:

```
<t:zone t:id="zone1" id="zone1">
    <t:form t:id="form1" id="form1" t:zone="zone1">
        <t:beaneditor t:id="filterEditor" t:object="filter">
        </t:beaneditor>
        ...
        <input id="submitFilter" t:id="submitFilter" class="button" t:type="submit" value="Submit" zone="zone1"/>
    </t:form>

    <t:form t:id="form2" id="form2" t:zone="^">
        <input id="resetFilter" t:id="resetFilter" class="button" t:type="submit" value="Reset" zone="zone1"/>
    </t:form>
</t:zone>
<t:zone t:id="zone2" id="zone2">
        <t:form t:id="form3" id="form3" t:zone="^" t:autofocus="true">
            ...
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="button"/>
        </t:form>
</t:zone>
<t:zone t:id="zone3" id="zone3">
    <t:form t:id="form4" id="form4" t:zone="^" t:autofocus="false">
        <t:errors/>

        <table>
            <t:grid t:source="dataSource"
                    t:model="beanModel"
                    t:row="entry"
                    t:encoder="encoder"
                    t:rowsPerPage="5"
                    t:pagerPosition="both"
                    t:inplace="true">

                    <p:cell1>
                    ...
                    </p:cell1>

                    <p:cell2>
                    ...
                    </p:cell2>

                    <p:cell3>
                    ...
                    </p:cell3>

                    <p:cell4>
                    ...
                    </p:cell4>

                    <p:cell5>
                    ...
                    </p:cell5>
            </t:grid>
        </table>
    </t:form>
</t:zone>
```

When I click to sort the cells on grid in zone3 (the sorting is done on DB side, via SQL), the table HTML duplicates and acts as another, separate table.

I've tried updating my zones like this:

```
if (request.isXHR()) {
    ajaxResponseRendered.addRender(zone1).addRender(zone2).addRender(zone3);
}
```

and like this:

```
if (request.isXHR()) {
    ajaxResponseRendered.addRender(zone1.getCliendId(), zone1.getBody()).addRender(zone2.getCliendId(), zone2.getBody()).addRender(zone3.getCliendId(), zone3.getBody());
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: It's very difficult to help without seeing the relevent code

Comment: Why have you nested your grid in a table tag? That will produce invalid HTML.